# Select Top n from XML File

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How to select last 1 Status from the following xml file where ContractID is 2 using C#?

```
<actions>
     <Action>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <ContractID>1</ContractID>
    <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
    <Date>2012-09-04 00:00:00.000</Date>
    <Reply/>
    <Status>4002</Status>
</Action>
    <Action>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <ContractID>2</ContractID>
    <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
    <Date>2012-09-04 00:00:00.000</Date>
    <Reply/>
    <Status>4005</Status>
</Action>
    <Action>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <ContractID>2</ContractID>
    <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
    <Date>2012-09-04 00:00:00.000</Date>
    <Reply/>
    <Status>4008</Status>
</Action>
</actions>
```

and how to select top n too using linq to xml or any other way

---

and what is the linq to xml code that is equivalent to the following sql query:

```
Select contracts.ID, contracts.ContractNo, 
    (select FieldName from tbl_SysType where ID =
    (select top 1 status from tbl_EmployeesActions where ContractID=contracts.ID and Status is not null order by ID desc ))as ContractStatus
from tbl_Contracts as contracts
```

if there are xml files named Contracts.xml, SysType.xml, and EmployeesActions.xml as below
Contracts.xml

```
<Contracts>
     <Contract>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <ContractNo>Mob124444</ContractNo>      
</Contract>
    <Contract>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <ContractNo>Mob124445</ContractNo>      
</Contract>
</Contracts>
```

EmployeesActions.xml

```
    <actions>
     <Action>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <ContractID>1</ContractID>
    <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
    <Date>2012-09-04 00:00:00.000</Date>
    <Reply/>
    <Status>4002</Status>
</Action>
    <Action>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <ContractID>2</ContractID>
    <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
    <Date>2012-09-04 00:00:00.000</Date>
    <Reply/>
    <Status>4005</Status>
</Action>
    <Action>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <ContractID>2</ContractID>
    <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
    <Date>2012-09-04 00:00:00.000</Date>
    <Reply/>
    <Status>4008</Status>
</Action>
</actions>
```

Systype.xml

```
<SysTypes>
    <systype>
        <ID>4002</ID>
        <FieldName>New</FieldName>
    </systype>
<systype>
        <ID>4005</ID>
        <FieldName>Opened</FieldName>
    </systype>
<systype>
        <ID>4008</ID>
        <FieldName>Closed</FieldName>
    </systype>
</SysTypes>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the code snippets for your both requirements:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"XMLFile.xml");

var statuses = doc.Descendants("Action")
                  .Where(s => s.Element("ContractID").Value.Equals("2"))
                  .Select(s => s.Element("Status").Value);
```

**Select Last Status where ContractID is 2**

```
var lastStatus = statuses.Last();
```

**Select Top N Statuses where ContractID is 2**

```
int N = 2; // assuming TOP 2
var topNStatuses = statuses.Take(N);
```

For your new requirement, you can use this code snippet as a replacement for your SQL query:

```
XDocument employees = XDocument.Load(@"EmployeesActions.xml");
XDocument contracts = XDocument.Load(@"Contracts.xml");
XDocument sysTypes = XDocument.Load(@"Systype.xml");

var result = employees.Descendants("Action")
            .Join(sysTypes.Descendants("systype"),
                e => e.Element("Status") != null ? e.Element("Status").Value : "",
                s => s.Element("ID").Value,
                (e, s) => new
                {
                    ID = e.Element("ID").Value,
                    ContractID = e.Element("ContractID").Value,
                    Status = s.Element("FieldName").Value
                })
            .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Status))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)
            .Take(1)
            .Join(contracts.Descendants("Contract"),
                e => e.ContractID,
                c => c.Element("ID").Value,
                (e, c) => new
                {
                    ContractID = c.Element("ID").Value,
                    ContractNo = c.Element("ContractNo").Value,
                    Status = e.Status
                });
```

Comment: thanks a LOT.I've added another part to the question kindly have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
please could u give me a reference that I can study linq to xml from?

Comment: Have a look at this reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Comment: in ur answer u didn't handle this part of the sql query
"select top 1 status from tbl_EmployeesActions". How to select top 1 for each contract?

Comment: how to handle the case that an <action> element has no child <status>? now a null exception raises

Comment: I hope you won't get exception in the absence of status. See my edited answer now.

Comment: Ok I didn't get the exception but this worked as inner join, how to convert it to right join? if status is not found contract appears in the result with status="not found". sorry for my too much questions

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = XElement.Load("data.xml").
                      Descendants("Action").
                      Where(x => x.Element("ContractID").Value == "2")
                      .Select(y => new
                       {
                            id = y.Element("ID").Value,
                            empId = y.Element("EmployeeID").Value,
                            contractId = y.Element("ContractID").Value,
                            date = y.Element("Date").Value
                       });
```

To Pick the Top N(1)

```
var top = result.Take(1);
```

To Pick the Last N(1)

```
var last = result.Skip(result.Count()-1);
```

Comment: Do you really feel that use of anonymous types is best practice here? Just wondering what your reasoning is.

Comment: @Leon, It's an easy change to make it a named type. Anonymous types will work fine too in a lot of situations .Without context from the OP an anonymous type illustrates the point.

Comment: Simple enough. Thanks for the explanation. I just wanted to make sure that the OP is aware of what your reasoning is in case they are new to LINQ or anonymous types.